# Get which direction the slider goes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, slide

I'm using JQueryUI and making a **"hue" color picker** with a single bar ("red, yellow, green, cyan, blue, magenta").

Thing is I wonder if there's a special event to determine whether if the user is currently sliding left or right, or is either incrementing or decrementing the value in the meantime.

As you can see, in this case, the `slidestart` event is useless: the only way I know is to store the previous variable and using an `if`, doing a comparison with `current_value` and `prev_value`. How?

Long story short:

When slider `value` is 0, red is 255.

When slider `value` is 255, yellow is value. *(until here it's ok)*

`If` slider `value` is being decremented from 510, then `red--;`

`If` slider `value` is being incremented from 255, then `red++;`

and so on...

Comment: wouldn't you be able to tell which direction it was going based on the orientation you set and by comparing the new values with the old ones?

Comment: No, there's no built-in way to tell if it moves left or right. you have to calculate that based on the initial value and the current value.

Comment: SteveKB: Thing is I don't know which event is adequate to this case. 
j08691: So, what can I do to detect if the slider value is being incremented or decremented while I'm moving the slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it's not possible out of the box to determine which way the slider moved.
However if you're building a hue slider I'm not sure why you'd need it anyway?

I just created such a slider myself and it seems to work fine as is.
Please note the calculations are hacked together quickly and could surely be written much more efficiently as this was just a test.

HTML:

```
<input type="range" max="1530" min="0" style="width:100%" value="0" />
<br/><span/>
```

JS:

```
    $('input').change(function () {
        var v = $(this).val();
        var r = v < 255 || v > 255 * 5 ? 255 : (v < 255 * 2 ? 255 - (v - 255) : (v > 255 * 4 ? v - 255 * 4 : 0));
        var g = v < 255 ? v : (v < 255 * 3 ? 255 : (v < 255 * 4 ? 255 - (v - 255 * 3) : 0));
        var b = v < 255 * 2 ? 0 : (v < 255 * 3 ? (v - 255 * 2) : (v < 255 * 5 ? 255 : (v < 255 * 6 ? 255 - (v - 255 * 5) : 0)));

        $('span').text(r + ' ' + g + ' ' + b);
        $('body').css('background', 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')');
    }).trigger('change');
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/aUZ2L/

Comment: It's intended to show the user many posibilities (or colours for a certain section of a webpage, as a debug mode) in one slider, without having to experiment with three of them instead. Just thinking about that makes me go to sleep and forget about picking colors, so I decided to make one of these to speed up the decisions. More efficient, just that I didn't know it was a pain in the nuts, I mean by making one of these. :/